# How to calculate the current page while using Search After?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, pagination, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

Currently, I am working on Elastic Search and doing pagination the data.
Particularly, the data is sorted with 2 fields:

- date, sort desc
- id, sort desc when date is same

With the given page size, I can calculate the `number of pages` by using `track_total_hit`.
However, the problem is that I cannot calculate the `current page` because the `sort key(date, id)` do not contain any information about the index of the records.

I have also considered using the `from` and `size`, but the number of my data is higher than 10,000 records. So that is impossible to use them. Also, I don't want to change the default configuration of `max_result_window` because that will affect the performance.

Do you have any solution to solve this? Thank you!

I have checked:

- [Paginate search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html)
- [Track total hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits)
- [Index configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html)

Comment: Did you try [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) you can get large results and do search

Comment: Hm I have though about the Scroll API, but it seems not good enough about the performance. Particularly, when I have 250,000 records, I need to do batching scroll 25 times to get the latest pages. Each scroll request cost around 0.4 second so in total I need roughly 10 seconds just to get 1 request.

Also, because of storing the scroll context, it costs a lot of memory when the traffic goes high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have researched and figured-out that this is a trade-off.

That is similar to [offset-pagination and keyset-pagination](https://vladmihalcea.com/sql-seek-keyset-pagination/) of SQL db.

The offset strategy is similar to the `Scroll API` which need to `scan from the beginning`, and it knows the `current page`.

Meanwhile, the `search after` is similar to the `keyset strategy`, which do `not need to scan from the beginning`, but `won't know the current page`.